# Make ListFragment open a Activity

Tags: android

Oke so i'm really new to android studio and android app dev in general but i wanted to make a app that my  youth movement could use as sort of a database but i ran into a problem.

So i have a drawer with all the groups and if you press the drawer buttons it opens a ListFragment with names and what i want to happen is when i press the name a activity shows up with the name a photo and a phone number. But i can't seem to figure out how to open a activity from that listFragment.

Here is the ListFragment.java

```
package app.jarifile.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
* Created by User on 23/09/2015.
*/
public class Givers_Fragment extends ListFragment {

Intent i;

String[] listitems = {
        "(Takleider)",
        "(Takleider)",
        "(Leider)",
        "(Leider)"
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), Test_Activity.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), Test_Activity.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), Test_Activity.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And this is the Test_Activity code.

```
package app.jarifile.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



/**
* Created by User on 24/09/2015.
*/

public class Test_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
}
```

This is what logcat says

09-28 18:48:28.915  24081-24081/app.jarifile.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.jarifile.test, PID: 24081
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {app.jarifile.test/app.jarifile.test.Test_Activity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1793)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1515)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4026)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3973)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4297)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4265)
            at app.jarifile.test.Givers_Fragment.onListItemClick(Givers_Fragment.java:51)
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1544)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3721)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5660)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
09-28 18:48:31.635  24081-24081/app.jarifile.test I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 24081 SIG: 9

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is happening when you select a list item? Nothing? Does your app crash?

Comment: The app crashes yes.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that gets produced when the app crashes? It should be available by inspecting the output of the `adb log` command or by looking at the "Android" window in Android Studio. Also, a potential cause of crashing is that you don't have a case for when you press the last item in the list (index 3). So you will try to call `startActivity()` with an uninitialized `Intent`.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean?
I'm really really really new to this and coding in general and how would i find and post that?

Comment: Does this article clarify it at all? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debugging-with-logcat.html

Comment: i edited the question with what i think you want

Comment: "Unable to find explicit activity class {app.jarifile.test/app.jarifile.test.Test_Activity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this?
Or send me to a place whee i find how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not declared `Test_Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. All Activities in your app must be declared there. Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
 <manifest ... >
    <application ... >
      <activity android:name=".Test_Activity" />
      ...
    </application ... >
  ...
  </manifest>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring

Answer (score 0):

try to replace startActivity(i) with getActivity().startActivity(i)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that does not seem to work for me.